# Enum, Delegate Dictionary collection where delegate points to an overloaded method

Tags: c#, .net

I have a generic collection (Dictionary), which stores an enum and delegate. So if the user provides an enum value to a method as a parameter, the corresponding delegate in the collection will get executed.

This method, which the delegate points to, is overloaded. When invoking the method, how can I choose which version of the method to execute?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are the overloads in your situation? Are the enums all of the same type, meaning that the delegates all have the same parameter type declarations? (Thinking of that, it wouldn't make a greal deal of sense). Maybe I'm missing something, but any clarification here would be helpful please.

Comment: The delegates take differing number of strings, that's all. I also have delegates working with other data types (in which case, the delegate must be a seperate one).

Comment: could you kindly check this question out tp://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593218

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delegate only points to a single overload - not to the "method group". By the time you get a delegate to a method, you have already done overload resolution. Usually, you can do this just in the compiler:

```
using System;
class Foo {
    int Bar() { return 1; }
    void Bar(int a) { }
    static void Main() {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Func<int> myDelegate = foo.Bar; // points to "int Bar()" version
    }
}
```

If the question relates to getting the overloaded method via reflection - then you can specify the pattern in the arguments to `Type.GetMethod()` (as a `Type[]`). This should give you the method you want.

To get a delegate from a `MethodInfo`, use `Delegate.CreateDelegate`.

Comment: I guess I could just store different delegate types in the collection. As the delegate itself has certain enforced properties (return type/parameters), it's a little shortsighted of me to ask how to invoke other overloads.

Comment: If you are storing different delegate types, are you using DynamicInvoke? That is very *slow* compared to storing a single type of delegate and using the typed Invoke.

Comment: I was using Invoke(). However, the code is a WIP. Thanks (I learn something new and realise a topic to look up in every one of your replies).

Answer (score 0):

A delegate as a specific signature.  When you instance a delegate with a Method that has overloads it will use the overload whose signature best matches the delegates signature.

Comment: This is the only way really. I could just wrap the delegates in a seperate class and perhaps invoke the desired delegate. A little bit of a hack, but I will try this.